# Parse response to JSON format

Tags: scala, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery from Scala. I tried the sample Scala code to call Google bigQuery API

Scala:

```
val queryInfo: QueryRequest = 
  new QueryRequest().setQuery(s"SELECT * FROM $PROJECT_ID:$dataSetId.$tableId;")
val queryRequest: Bigquery#Jobs#Query = 
  bigquery.jobs().query(PROJECT_ID, queryInfo)
val queryResponse: QueryResponse = 
  queryRequest.execute()
```

Above BQ returns:

```
{
  "jobComplete":true,
  "jobReference":{
    "jobId":"job_xxx",
    "projectId":"xxx"
  },
  "kind":"bigquery#queryResponse",
  "rows":[{"f":[{"v":"1"},{"v":"1364206559422"}]}],
  "schema": {
    "fields":[
      {"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"id","type":"STRING"},
      {"mode":"NULLABLE","name":"timestamp","type":"INTEGER"}
    ]
  },
  "totalRows":"1",
  "pageToken":"xxxx"
}
```

Please help me parse the values from above the results in JSON Format or change the query to return the result of the format like this:

```
{"id": "1", "timestamp": "1364206559422"}
```

Comment: I retagged as it looks like Scala to me.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. You're right... Mistake fixed

Answer (score 0):

I like [lift json](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json/).

Look at the lotto example, it's straight forward with case classes